# Display an image when button is clicked

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I need to display two images when the button is clicked. First the user will browse for the two images and after clicking the third button it should display the two images. I have this code so far. I'm a complete newbie in vb

```
 Dim dialog As New OpenFileDialog()
    If DialogResult.OK = dialog.ShowDialog Then
        TextBox2.Text = dialog.FileName
    End If
```

Comment: add imagecontrol to form and on click of third button set imagecontrol.src = dialog.FileName

Comment: where will i find the imagecontrol?

Comment: on the control toolbar , you have an image button right ?

Comment: are you reffering to the picture box.sorry i'm really new to vb. I have three button 2 for browsing the images and the third button to display the image

Comment: no issues , see all I would like to say that , you need to have 2 picture boxes and have their src set at the click of third command button

Comment: so i already have two picture boxes so where do i get the src for each picture box?

Comment: on the third button's click event you need to add picture1.picture=loadpicture(textbox1.text)    picture2.picture=loadpicture(textbox2.text)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fdialog As New OpenFileDialog()
    fdialog.FileName = String.Empty
    fdialog.Multiselect = True

    If fdialog.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        If fdialog.FileNames.Length = 2 Then
            PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fdialog.FileNames(0))
            TextBox1.Text = fdialog.FileNames(0)
            PictureBox2.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fdialog.FileNames(1))
            TextBox2.Text = fdialog.FileNames(1)
        ElseIf fdialog.FileNames.Length = 1 Then
            PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fdialog.FileName)
            TextBox1.Text = fdialog.FileName
            PictureBox2.Image = Nothing
            TextBox2.Text = String.Empty
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

the following code goes in the click event of the "load" button.
regards ...